# PL/SQL job procedure does not insert decimal values to table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a scheduled job which calls following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PC."INSERT_AMOUNTS" is  
    promo_am number;
    cursor combs is
        select combo_id from product_to_product_view;
    cursor promos is
        select id from products where object_type in (3,12);
begin
    delete from amounts;
    for comb_row in combs loop
        for promos_row in promos loop
        begin
            promo_am:= get_product_promo_price(comb_row.combo_id,promos_row.id);
        end;
           if promo_am>-1 then
            insert into amounts (combo_id, promo_id, discount_amount) values (comb_row.combo_id, promos_row.id,promo_am );                          
           end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;  

commit;

end;
/
```

Problem is that if promo_am is decimal number (i.e. '33,55704698'), it is not inserted in 'amounts' table - but ONLY if I call procedure for all possible combos and promos.

If I call procedure for specific combos or promos only, all is inserted well.
Function get_product_promo_price always returns data (number) for all combos and promos.

For example if I change cursors to

```
cursor combs is
    select combo_id from product_to_product_view;
cursor promos is
    select id from products where object_type in (3,12) and id=1871;
```

Function get_product_promo_price returns '33,55704698' for combo_id=2107 and promo_id=1871 and it is successfully inserted in amounts table.

But if I change cursor promo to "fetch all", that is

```
cursor promos is
        select id from products where object_type in (3,12);
```

then there is no record in amounts table for combo_id=2107 and promo_id=1871.

Comment: Please provide ddl for objects "products" and "product_to_product_view", for function "get_product_promo_price " and some sample data (as scripts, not screenshots)

Comment: INSERT won't happen if a) PROMO_AM isn't > -1, b) PROMOS cursor returns nothing, c) COMBS cursor return nothing. As COMBS doesn't have WHERE clause, then it is either PROMOS cursor or PROMO_AM that prevents INSERT. You have the data, we don't so - investigate it.

Comment: It would be useful to have a [mcve], and also to know how you are testing and reproducing the problem; and what debugging you have done. From what you've shown the only thing that really stands out is that '33,55704698 is a string not a number, which might suggest you're relying on implicit conversion somewhere, which could work or break for different filters, and maybe when called from the scheduler vs. your own session. Perhaps an exception is being thrown and you're squashing it somewhere. The extra begin/end might indicate an exception handler you haven't shown, for example.

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry, I was pasting result from Toad which formats number to string in data grid output. If I replace insert clause with            `if promo_am>-1 then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(promo_am );                    
           end if;` I can see that procedure outputs 33.55704698 to dbms

Answer (score 0):

@AlexPoole was right - problem is that scheduled job did not have same nls_env as owner of procedure that it was running.

Documentation states that that scheduled job and its children will inherit NLS env from the creator's.

```
select j.job_name,
       substr(j.nls_env, instr(j.nls_env, 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'), 40)
  from user_scheduler_jobs j
 where j.job_name in ('INSERT_AMOUNTS_JOB');
```

Since I created this job a year ago, it has `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',.'`

When I checked  PC."INSERT_AMOUNTS" owner parameter via

```
select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter='NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
```

Result was
`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,'`

It seems that our DBA changed NLS_ENV in the meantime, probably when they patched the database. So I just need to drop and recreate the job so that it picks up new NLS_ENV params (one can also set it via sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute).

TL;DR the problem was not in procedure but in scheduled job that called it.